# Wordpress Breadcrumbs

Tags: wordpress, bread-board

As we only have one category for all posts, it doesn't make sense to have the category link in our breadcrumbs. So instead of:

frontpage/category_name/post_name

We would like:

frontpage/post_archive (home)/post_name

Can't find any article on how to do this properly. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Did u make the custom breadcrumb or from plugin show us the code please

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Yoast SEO breadcrumbs, as we're using this plugin anyways. To swap WooCommerce breadcrumbs for Yoast, use the following code:

```
// Replace WooCommerce breadcrumbs with Yoast bredcrumbs
remove_action('init', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content','woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','my_yoast_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
if (!function_exists('my_yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
  function my_yoast_breadcrumb() {
    yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>');
  }
}
```

Comment: You can actually easily filter Yoast's breadcrumb path. I added a link to another such code example above.

Comment: Thanks, but they have their own fields for overriding this in the default settings. Yoast works quite good :)

Answer (score -1):

Please use below plugin. its good plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/

Comment: Hmm.. Was looking for a simple snippet for functions.php. Would prefer not to add many plugins to our page. I'd rather use Yoast breadcrumbs.

Comment: You can modify Yoast's breadcrumb path by adding a filter to `wpseo_breadcrumb_links`. Kind of this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100012/how-to-add-a-page-to-the-yoast-breadcrumbs.